# z/OS FTP Directory Listing - Column “Volume” Valid Values

Tags: ftp, ibm-server

Besides the volume ID and status "Migrated", what other values might get returned by IBM z/OS MVS FTP server, in column "Volume" (default DATASETMODE directory listing format)?

For example:

```
Volume Unit    Referred Ext Used Recfm Lrecl BlkSz Dsorg Dsname
Migrated                                                F010317A.FD2F
SS1010 3390   2017/05/31  1    1  FB     309 27810  PS  F010917A.FSSP
```

Looking at this with an eye toward parsing directory listing results in an FTP client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems column Volume may contain three values, for directory listings produced with default DATASETMODE format:

1. Volume ID
2. Migrated
3. MIGRAT

For example:

```
  function IsMVSMigrated(const AData : String) : Boolean;
  begin
    Result := TextStartsWith(AData, 'Migrated') or TextStartsWith(AData, 'MIGRAT');  {do not localize}
  end;
```

Source: 
https://github.com/skelter/Indy/blob/master/Lib/Protocols/IdFTPListParseMVS.pas